# Yiic message translation failing

Tags: yii, message, yiic

I'm trying to prep translation for a module. my config.php is just a copy from the framework, modified 'languages' for just 'fr'.
Here's my config.php file

```
return array(
  'language'=>'en',
  'sourcePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
  'messagePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'messages',
  'languages'=>array('fr'),
  'fileTypes'=>array('php'),
  'overwrite'=>true,
  'exclude'=>array(
    '.svn',
    '.gitignore',
    '/i18n/data',
    '/messages',
  ),
);
```

The command runs properly, and I get this kind of output:

```
Extracting messages from <MyProject>/protected/modules/admin/views/significantEvent/view.php...
...
Extracting messages from <MyProject>/protected/modules/admin/views/projectProgress/update.php...
```

But that's it. Nothing is changed anywhere, there's no new files, nothing was edited. It seems like the command didn't do anything but read all the files and tell me where to translate. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to edit your messages/config.php file so it includes the contents of the module.

set the sourcepath part of the array to

```
'sourcePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
```

And set the 'exclude' part to

```
'exclude' => array(
        '.svn',
        '.gitignore',
        '/assets',
        '/css',
        '/images',
        '/js',
        '/yii',
        '.htaccess',
        'index.php',
        'index-test.php'
    )
```

Comment: Message edited to include my config.php.  Sourcepath and message path are already configured

Comment: And you are obviously using Yii::t('name','string') around the strings to be translated?